# Writing video from multiple cameras

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video

I have multiple videos stored. I wanted to write a video from these multiple videos by giving the path to the video capture object. I wanted to write a video that takes frames from these multiple videos. So is there a way to read the frames from the different videos without creating multiple capture objects

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to save the filepaths to your videos in an array, then use VideoCapture::open method, as illustrated:

```
video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi','''other args''')
filePath=["File/Path/1","File/Path/2"]#and so on
cap=cv2.Videocapture(0)#just for initialization, we don't need live cam

for i in range(len(filePath)):
   cap.open(filePath[i])
   while(cap.isOpened())
       ret,img=cap.read()
       video.write(img)
video.release()
```